# StateMachine - действие на смену состояния

Tags: java, spring

Написал реализацию state machine, пользуясь [гайдом от Spring'a](https://projects.spring.io/spring-statemachine/).

Не могу добиться никакой реации на смену состояния, хотя сами состояния меняются успешно. Возможно, я неверно понял цель класса Beans. Также грешил на аннотацию @Configuration в классе конфигурации, т.к. в гайде она указана кратко, без пути. Но других её вариантов мне IDE не предложила.

Вот эти сообщения в методах на консоль не выводятся:

```
import org.springframework.statemachine.annotation.OnTransition;
import org.springframework.statemachine.annotation.WithStateMachine;

@WithStateMachine
public class Beans {

  @OnTransition(target = "CLOSED_DOOR")
  void closeDoor() {
      System.out.println("метод closeDoor");
  }

  @OnTransition(target = "GOING")
  void startMoving() {
      System.out.println("метод startMoving");
  }
```

}

Класс конфигурации:

```
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnableStateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineStateConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineTransitionConfigurer;;

import java.util.EnumSet;


@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
public class Configuration extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {
    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
            throws Exception {
        states
                .withStates()
                .initial(States.STAY)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(States.class));
    }

@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
        throws Exception {
    transitions
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.STAY).target(States.CLOSED_DOOR)
            .event(Events.CLOSE_DOOR)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(States.CLOSED_DOOR).target(States.GOING)
            .event(Events.MOVE);
}
```

}

Ну и запуск (в консоль выводятся верные состояния, соотв. событиям):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine;

public class App {
    @Autowired
    static StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        stateMachine = Builder.getMachine();
        stateMachine.start();

        stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.CLOSE_DOOR);
        System.out.println(stateMachine.getState()); // ObjectState [getIds()=[CLOSED_DOOR]

        stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.MOVE);
        System.out.println(stateMachine.getState()); // ObjectState [getIds()=[GOING]
    }
```

Зависимость одна.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-statemachine-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

[Есть решение.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56490586/10382092)

Проблема заключалась в одновременном использовании аннотации @WithStateMachine и Builder.getMachine(), что противоречит друг другу.